# Can you suggest illustrator tutorial to attain the following serif font effect given in the image below

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-design, serif

How can i recreate the following serif font effect given in the image in illustrator?[image: Sans serif effect]

Comment: offset a outlined text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on joojaa's answer...

Right-Click or CTRL + Click on your text and `Create Outlines`

[image: 1]

Then, you want to offset your path

[image: 2]

Play with your settings

[image: 3]

I've colored my result in yellow, so you can see the newly created objects

[image: 4]

Delete the paths that you no longer want

[image: 5]

For future reference, this site works more as an "I've tried _____ and I'm having trouble with _____" kind of site, rather than a "Someone show me how to _____" site.